# Jenkins SCM Polling - Biweekly (Every Two Weeks)

Tags: jenkins

Currently I am polling SCM

`H H(0-8) * * 5`

Which I intend to mean: poll between midnight and 8am on Friday.

What I would like is to poll every OTHER Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this in Jenkins, but I believe the normal cron syntax would be: `0 0-8 * * 5/2`

Comment: That *kinda* makes sense. I've give it a whirl!

Comment: It doesn't compile in Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not work in Jenkins:

> Invalid input: "0 0-8 * * 5/2": line 1:12: unexpected token: /

So take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33788028/3890673) (and vote that up in case it helps):

`H H 8-14,22-28 * 5`

"Run at some hour and some minute (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302727/3890673) for the meaning of `H`) every Friday (=the 5th day, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18919183/3890673)), if that Friday happens to be between day 8-14 or 22-28 of month." Looks good in my local Jenkins, skipping the run on January 31st:

> Would last have run at Friday, January 24, 2020 12:39:59 AM UTC; would next run at Friday, February 14, 2020 12:39:59 AM UTC.

Comment: okay...

it gave the following warning messages

Short cycles in the day-of-month field will behave oddly near the end of a month
Would last have run at Saturday, March 28, 2020 8:02:52 AM CET; would next run at Saturday, April 11, 2020 8:02:52 AM CEST.

Answer (score -1):

The following statement helps you to run it bi-weekly at 08:00 A.M on Friday.

```
00 08 */2 * 5
```

Comment: `*/2` would be every second day-of-month, wouldn't it?

Comment: it works fine with Jenkins at the time I specified choosing the option "Build periodically".