# Crontab Day of the Week syntax

Tags: linux, cron, system-administration

In crontab does the Day of the Week field run from `0 - 6` or `1 -7`?

I am seeing conflicting information on this.  wikipedia states `0-6` and other sites I have seen are `1-7`.

Also what would be the implication or either using `0` or `7` incorrectly?  i.e. would the cron still run?

Answer (score 533, accepted):

`0` and `7` both stand for Sunday, you can use the one you want, so writing 0-6 or 1-7 has the same result.

Also, as suggested by @Henrik, it is possible to replace numbers by shortened name of days, such as `MON`, `THU`, etc:

```
0 - Sun      Sunday
1 - Mon      Monday
2 - Tue      Tuesday
3 - Wed      Wednesday
4 - Thu      Thursday
5 - Fri      Friday
6 - Sat      Saturday
7 - Sun      Sunday
```

Graphically, `* * * * * command to be executed` stands for:

| minute | hour | day of month | month | day of week |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (0-59) | (0-23) | (1-31) | (1-12) | (1-7) |  |
| * | * | * | * | * | command to be executed |

Or using the old style:

```
 ┌────────── minute (0 - 59)
 │ ┌──────── hour (0 - 23)
 │ │ ┌────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ ┌──── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ │ │ ┌── day of week (0 - 6 => Sunday - Saturday, or
 │ │ │ │ │                1 - 7 => Monday - Sunday)
 ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
 * * * * * command to be executed
```

Finally, if you want to specify day by day, you can separate days with commas, for example `SUN,MON,THU` will exectute the command only on sundays, mondays on thursdays.

You can read further details in [Wikipedia's article about Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and check a cron expression online with [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru).

Comment: ok thats what i didnt realise Sunday can be a 0 or 7.  thanks

Comment: Be aware that you cannot do: `Sat-Sun`, only `6-7` or `Sat,Sun`

Comment: Can you confirm this is case-insensitive? You switch a few times among `SUN`, `Sun`, `Sunday` in your response

Comment: @MichaelChirico oh, good point. Checking [Wikipedia's article about Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) I read _The month and weekday abbreviations are not case-sensitive_.

Comment: @pkowalczyk Even though 'man 5 crontab' confirms your claim, named day-of-week lists work fine in crond provided by cronie-1.5.2-4 (CentOS 8)

Answer (score 132):

```
    :-) Sunday    |    Sun  ->  0
                  |  
        Monday    |    Mon  ->  1
       Tuesday    |    Tue  ->  2
     Wednesday    |    Wed  ->  3
      Thursday    |    Thu  ->  4
        Friday    |    Fri  ->  5
      Saturday    |    Sat  ->  6
                  |  
    :-) Sunday    |             7
```

As you can see above, the numbers `0` and `7` are both assigned to Sunday. There are also the English abbreviated days of the week listed, which can also be used in the crontab.

**Examples of Number or Abbreviation Use**

```
15 09 * * 5,6,0             command
15 09 * * 5,6,7             command
15 09 * * 5-7               command
15 09 * * Fri,Sat,Sun       command
```

The four examples do all the same and execute a command every Friday, Saturday, and Sunday at 9.15 o'clock.

**In Detail**

Utilising both `0` and `7` to represent Sunday is advantageous for creating weekday ranges<sup>[*]</sup> that start or end with Sunday, such as `0-2` or `5-7`. Ranges must start with the lower number and finish with the higher number. Abbreviations like `Sun`, `Mon`, `Tue`, etc. can also be used. But `Sun` is not allowed to be set at the end of the range. For example, you cannot shorten `Fri,Sat,Sun` to `Fri-Sun`.

---

[*] In the context of a crontab, a range is used to specify a continuous sequence of time units, such as minutes, hours, days, or weekdays. Ranges in crontab are represented using a hyphen-minus character (-) between the lower and upper bound values. For instance, a range of weekdays from Monday (1) to Wednesday (3) would be represented as `1-3`.

Comment: For clarity, “The abbreviations cannot be used to define a weekday range.” statement here seems to be a way of saying that one can’t separate abbreviations by hyphen‐minus characters, only commas. In other words, `Fri,Sat,Sun` can’t be shortened to `Fri-Sun`.

Comment: @PatrickDark, I edited the answer, hopefully making it more understandable.

Comment: @PatrickDark But in my crontab mon-fri works, I use it on debian. Also works thu-sat but thu-sun does not work. Why is it possible that thu-sun does not work but thu-sat works?

Comment: @T0maas I guess `Sun` is handled like `0`, it can only be placed at the beginning as the first day. If you want to set Sunday as the last day, you can use the numbers and use `7` for Sunday.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use day names like `Mon` for Monday, `Tue` for Tuesday, etc. It's more human friendly.

Comment: This won't work for some distributions; testing with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, I got "/tmp/crontab.Nuq9GE/crontab":24: bad day-of-week"

Comment: @Nikita check for typos or extra spaces. I have both a "Mon-Fri" and a "Thu" in my crontab on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and both work just fine. I suspect if there's a space between any of the characters, you'd end up with an error.