# How to automate execution of commands by day and hour on Debian?

Tags: bash, raspbian

So I am a working on a simple home lightning control using Raspberry Pi (and raspbian). I can turn or dim lights by writing commands  to a zigbee dongle (through a serial interface) by running a command like:

```
sudo echo "#1*##*1231#*9#" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

One of its main functions is to program "scenes" so you can turn lights on and off at certain hour or day.

So how can I automate a bash command to run lets say monday, tuesday and saturday at 8:55AM every week? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look into crontab (man crontab) this makes what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5). Those threads will help you:

- [how to set cronjob for 2 days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days)
- [Crontab Day of the Week syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919151/crontab-day-of-the-week-syntax)

So:

```
crontab -e  # edit crontab file
```

and then insert

```
55 8 * * 1,2,6 /usr/local/bin/my_cool_script
```

In case crontab is not flexible enough for your needs, you can use Ruby [Rufus scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler)