# How to force ubuntu server make command hourly?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-18.04, cron-task

with this crontab i force nginx and supervisor to do a command in every hour and in every 4 hours. But how can i force to make this command in every 10 minutes:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
# Restart streams
0 */4   * * *   root    supervisorctl stop all; rm -f /etc/nginx/hls/*/*.{ts,mp4}; supervisorctl start all

0 */1   * * *   root    supervisorctl start all; 
#
0 */1   * * *   root    rm -f /etc/nginx/hls/*/*.{ts,mp4};
```

in  `0 */1   * * *   root    supervisorctl start all;`  this command `*/1`  forces to make it in evry 1 hour. But can i define minutes?

Comment: Maybe this can be of help to create the syntax you need https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 0):

minutes is the first parameter. 
This will execute the command every 10 minutes.

```
*/10 * * * * root [your command]
```

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18919183/2377026)