# Jenkins bi-weekly build

Tags: jenkins

How to setup jenkins job to only run biweekly at 8 AM in the morning.

Considering only the working days, Monday through Friday.

Basically running the build every second Friday.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following [cron expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression)

```
0 8 8-14,22-28 * 5
```

The format explained looks as:

```
{Minute} {Hour} {DayOfMonth} {Month} {DayofWeek}
```

[image: JMeter Jenkins Schedule]

You might also want to check out [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) for more information regarding how to set up Jenkins for JMeter tests execution.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, refer issue [JENKINS-19756](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19756)

However, a workaround that doesn't look good but works, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995498/2618028) answer.

Another workaround, that looks fine but works little erratically:
*0 7 1-7,15-21,29-31 * 1* 
"all Mondays in 1st, 3rd and 5th week"
(error in this one: if there's a 5th week, it works its next week as well as its the first week of next month)