# How to schedule a build in Jenkins on alternate Saturday

Tags: jenkins

I want to schedule a Jenkins job which will back up my database on alternate Saturday I am using this expression  but I am confused how to find out alternate Saturdays in a month

```
* * * * 6
```

Comment: you can try running on particular days of month. `10 22 1-7,15-21,29-31  * 6`

Comment: @Kaushik if I will use this then for each month I need to change the expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want Jenkins job to build every two weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785196/i-want-jenkins-job-to-build-every-two-weeks)

Comment: No, this will run on every alternate Saturday for each month. see there will be only one saturday between 1-7 and 15-21 so it will ran on those saturdays and 29-31 if there will be it will run on that. but for next month it will continue the same. So its monthly not as per your requirement.