# Cron entry for alternate tuesday

Tags: linux, jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Can someone provide the cron entry for every alternative Tuesday

I have tried 0 0 */14 * 2 but it is running every Tuesday

thanks,
surya

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want Jenkins job to build every two weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785196/i-want-jenkins-job-to-build-every-two-weeks)

Answer (score 0):

i think the exemple here will help u  : 30 00 1-5,15-19,29-31 * 4

look here for more information: https://sharadchhetri.com/run-cron-job-alternate-week-day/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it didn't help